# Useful Delphi code templates

Tags: delphi, code-snippets, code-templates

I've been programming in Delphi for a little over two years now, and I've only got maybe 5 custom templates, I feel as though I should have more.

If anyone has any particularly useful ones it would be great to have a nice repository of them here on stackoverflow.

I don't care whether you use the Delphi 2009 syntax or Delphi 7, but if the code you'd be generating only works on a particular version, please mention that.

Answer (score 11):

There are a handful of useful ones here, including a few based on CodeRush.  These are the live templates, so they work in Delphi 2006 and up.

http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Live_Templates

Answer (score 8):

Very handy output debug string plus formatting

---

**Name:**
ods
**Description:**
Output Debug String with Format
**Code:**

```
OutputDebugString(PAnsiChar(format('|',[])));
```

---

also, if I want to leave it in the code:

**Name:**
dods
**Description:**
Output Debug String with ifdef debug
**Code:**

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG}   
   OutputDebugString(PAnsiChar(format('|',[])));   
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: We have a little procedure ODS(const s: string) instead. :)

Comment: wow i have all most the same shortcut, but with out the format, I think im going to add that now :) thanks

Comment: Little reminder from the unicode conversion front - change to OutputDebugStringW or OutputDebugStringA accordingly

Comment: Use PChar instead of PAnsiChar.  That way, it'll work fine both in Unicode and non-Unicode versions of Delphi.

Answer (score 5):

This one is pretty handy because it always shows up first when I hit ctrl-j (so my shortcut is ctrl-j enter)

---

**Name:**
//*
**Description:**
Comment Line
**Code:**

```
//******************************************************************************
```

I use it to start documentation around methods.  It sure beats hitting '*' 78 times.

Comment: I use a similar one to this one, but its named hr and is a line of dashes rather than asterisks.

Comment: I can't think of where I'd put such a comment that would actually be useful. I.e. in the sense of explaining what the code does.

Comment: That's the first part of a useful comment, (i.e. //********** //* This function does something awesome //*************)  My company requires at a minimum //************** between procedures, which can get tedious when you're a guy who likes to use properties with get/set methods.

Answer (score 4):

If you do a lot of work on datasets these are handy.

**Name:**
fbn

**Description:**
DataSet FieldByName

```
|DataSet|.FieldByName( '|Field|' )|end|
```

**Name:**
pbn

**Description:**
DataSet ParamByName

```
|DataSet|.ParamByName( 'P_|Param|' )|end|
```

Comment: I use a program to auto-generate those codes. Code-complete-40-times is still too many.

Answer (score 3):

I did a couple that saved me lots of time. A few of those took the monotone out of property declarations. Then I did some to create type-safe enumerators, object lists and bucket lists. I probably should do one for collections too, but haven't yet.

These are all available on my [blog](http://sourcecodeadventures.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/12-delphi-code-templates-to-save-keystrokes/).