# Delphi 7 Personal: class wizard extension?

Tags: delphi, class, delphi-7, wizard

I'm wondering if there's any class wizard extension (maybe GExperts extension?) for Delphi 7 Personal? 
The most important feature for me is to automatically generate properties getters / setters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why need an extension - just use code templates. take a look at this [**eTutorial**](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+I+Foundations/Chapter+1+Delphi+7+and+Its+IDE/The+Delphi+Editor/) and read sections **Class Completion (Ctrl+Shift+C) and Code Templates (Ctrl+J)**.

this could help too (not all for D7) 
[Useful Delphi code templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885024/useful-delphi-code-templates)

if you really want an extension take a look at [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) - they have code templates too (IDE Enhancements -> Input Helper Settings) also with some examples for eg. properties which you can add/edit yourself.

--reinhard